# OOP questions, instantiating an object

Tags: c#, oop

I have an object animal:

```
class Animal{

}
```

I want to create an object of Animal, is there a difference between the lines on the class main?

```
class main{
     var myVar = new Animal();        // case 1
     Animal myAnimal = new Animal();  // case 2
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no difference. [MSDN var description](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb383973.aspx) says:

> An implicitly typed local variable is strongly typed just as if you had declared the type yourself, but the compiler determines the type.

In other words, it is just a helpful way of writing the same code, with a little help of compiler. It is quite usefull when you are creating long types like:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string, List<int>>();
```

instead of:

```
Dictionary<string, List<int>> dict = new Dictionary<string, List<int>>();
```

but was added at the same time as LINQ and anonymous types to make LINQ queries:

```
var outpus = someList.Where(x => x.SomeData == 0)
                     .Select(new 
                     {
                         FieldA = x.SomeField
                     });
```

so here compiler determines the anonymous type, you do not have to specify it.

You can read more about it [on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/bb384061.aspx).